jquery trying to get the first 50 characters of input from a magstripe reader, process the data and select the next field without overflow
I am using a magstripe reader to input data into a text field.  I want the first 50 characters only so I am using on.('input',function) to wait for the first 50 characters, then I parse the data and select() the next input filed.
My problem is that any data beyond the 50 characters is being inserted into the input that is select()ed.
I've tried using max-length=50, deselecting all inputs (using blur()) before selecting the next input, selecting a hidden input first before selecting the desired input, selecting the desired input, clearing it and then re-selecting it.  Nothing works.
<!-- Here is my test code. -->
<body>
<form name="test" id="test">
    <input type="text" name="test_text1" id="test_text1" maxlength="50">
    <input type="text" name="test_text2" id="test_text2">
    <span id="nuttin">&nbsp;</span>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#test_text1").select();
       $("#test_text1").on('input',function(){lookForSwipe(this)}) ;
    });
    function lookForSwipe(field){
        var fldValue = field.value;
        var fldID    = field.id;
        if(fldValue.length == 50){
            $("#test_text2").select();
        }
    }
</script>
</body>


In your example, you have mistyped maxlength attribute. Probably it's the cause.

Thanks for pointing that out Kosh, Unfortunately correcting that does not solve the issue.

The magstripe reader inputs data continuously, so if you switch focus to another input field immediately after the first 50 characters, any remaining characters will be inserted into the next selected input field.
I'd say, use a flag to temporarily disable input processing and then clear any remaining data from the input field after processing the first 50 characters.
<body>
<form name="test" id="test">
    <input type="text" name="test_text1" id="test_text1" maxlength="50">
    <input type="text" name="test_text2" id="test_text2">
    <span id="nuttin">&nbsp;</span>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#test_text1").select();
        $("#test_text1").on('input', function() { lookForSwipe(this) });
    });

    let processingInput = false;

    function lookForSwipe(field) {
        if (processingInput) return;
        
        var fldValue = field.value;
        if (fldValue.length >= 50) {
            processingInput = true;
            field.value = fldValue.substring(0, 50);
            
            // Move focus to the next input field
            $("#test_text2").select();
            
            // Clear any additional data after processing
            setTimeout(() => {
                field.value = "";
                processingInput = false;
            }, 0);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>


processingInput: boolean flag

The lookForSwipe function checks if the input length is 50 or more
characters. If >50, processingInput = true to prevent further
processing until we're done.

Input field's value is truncated to the first 50 characters, and
then focus is moved to the next input field.

Input field is cleared after processing to remove any extra
characters that may have been entered.  setTimeout function =
field is cleared after the focus is moved.

processingInput flag is reset to false to allow normal input
processing to resume.



Thanks for that Joshua George!  I needed to set the timeout to 500 but it works!  Now I can get on with my life!!!
